# Why my Navigation and Normal Buttons text and images are not visible but actionable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Why my Navigation and Normal Buttons text and images are not visible but actionable, when i build app on iphone and as well as when i check app after building an app on simulator?

This is how i am adding button to navigation bar:

```
    @objc func moreNavigationButton() -> UIBarButtonItem {

    let barButton:UIButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    barButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(moreNavigationButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    barButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    barButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_more"), for: .normal)
    barButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    let barButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: barButton)
    barButtonItem.width = 30
    
    return barButtonItem
}
```

In viewWillAppear() function i am calling the above method like following:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.moreNavigationButton()]
```

Comment: Use view debugger check if frames are fine for your buttons and images, for text check if text color is same as back ground color, try adding border or background colors to check if its the issue of frame or content (text / image)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Will check and let you know here. Thanks

Comment: Is the issue happenning only with `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari No sir. The issue is with normal buttons as well

Comment: Not sure, simply change the simulator and check or just delete derived data and kill the simulator and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below extension was causing this problem. Now i commented it and it is solved.

```
extension UIButton {
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            if imageView != nil {
                imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: (bounds.width - 5), bottom: 5, right: 5)
                titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: (imageView?.frame.width)!)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All right now we have different setting up for button in my side I usually do like that

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped)) 
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

then after I set 2 barButtonItem

```
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
let play = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Play", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(playTapped))
```

Here I had them to navigation items
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, play]

I suppose you need to set Bar button item instead of button.

Thanks to Paul Hudson content It's always helpful
Let me know if it's helpful

Comment: No. My buttons background color is different and text color is white.

Comment: How did you set you button can we have some code to see if it may cause trouble?

Comment: I review my last answers let me know if it's helpful

Comment: Giovanni is correct, you are using the wrong type of button

Comment: @latenitecoder I want to create a custom button in navigation bar so i have added that code. How can i achieve that with the Giovanni code?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning every one So this morning I create a new project with the system of create your own navigationBar and your own barButton. Feel free to download fork do some pull request or whatever.

https://github.com/Gioovannii/Navigation-bar/tree/main

Comment: I have downloaded your project. As per my research this problem might be causing because of Navigation controller and TabView controller. Please say is this is correct..

Comment: Doesn't matter if you using tableviewController ou UIViewController either one or the other can be embed in navigation Controller if you didn't embed them in a navigation controller setting up programaticly will have no effect

Comment: I have embedded them.

Comment: If my answer fit you please choice as accepted answer it can help other people @VaishuSH

Comment: No way Alright, I don't know what I can do for help

Comment: My All buttons text, Navigation bar text and buttons and Keyboard button are not visible but all are actionable. Not able to solve it from yesterday please help me to solve this.

Comment: How can they be actionable and not visible

Comment: That is what i am not able to figure out

Comment: It's posible to have screen shot?

Comment: The problem was with the button layouts so the text and images weren't displaying now it is solved! Thanks.